# LINQ multiple left outer join with a "or" clause

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5

So basically, I try here to transfer this query in LINQ.

```
DECLARE @p1 UniqueIdentifier SET @p1 = 'AC1D85C1-28F1-46A3-9C6A-3B7446609A2A'
DECLARE @p2 UniqueIdentifier SET @p2 = NEWID()
SELECT
    [MTD].[Description],
    [MTD].[MessageTypeID],
    ISNULL([AMT].[ApplicationMessageTypeID], NEWID()),
    ISNULL([AMT].[EventForwardingRuleID], '1001')
FROM [dbo].[MessageType] as [MT]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[MessageTypeDescription] AS [MTD] 
        ON [MT].[MessageTypeID] = [MTD].[MessageTypeID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ApplicationMessageType] AS [AMT] 
        ON [AMT].[MessageTypeID] = [MT].[MessageTypeID]
        AND ( [AMT].[ApplicationID] = @p1 OR [AMT].[ApplicationID] IS NULL )
WHERE [MTD].[Culture] = 'fr'
```

I know for the most part that the query should look like something like that:

```
(from mt in db.MessageTypes
join mtd in db.MessageTypeDescriptions
    on mt.MessageTypeID equals mtd.MessageTypeID
join amt in db.ApplicationMessageTypes
    on new { mt.MessageTypeID, (applicationId || null) } equals new { amt.MessageTypeID, amt.ApplicationID }
    into appMessageTypes
from amt in appMessageTypes.DefaultIfEmpty()
where mtd.Culture == culture
select new ApplicationEditEventTypeModel
{
    ApplicationMessageTypeID = amt.ApplicationMessageTypeID == null ? Guid.NewGuid() : amt.ApplicationMessageTypeID,
    Description = mtd.Description,
    MessageTypeID = mtd.MessageTypeID,
    EventForwardingRuleID = amt.EventForwardingRuleID == null ? 0 : amt.EventForwardingRuleID
});
```

The part here where I'm really not sure is the "ApplicationMessageTypes" part. For a multiple left join query I'd use the `new {} equals new {}` construct but in this case, I have 2 clauses `( [AMT].[ApplicationID] = @p1 OR [AMT].[ApplicationID] IS NULL )`.

Should I use something like `new { mt.MessageTypeID, new { applicationId ,null }} equals new { amt.MessageTypeID, amt.ApplicationID }`? This seems too strange to be real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(from mt in db.MessageTypes
join mtd in db.MessageTypeDescriptions
    on mt.MessageTypeID equals mtd.MessageTypeID
from amt in db.ApplicationMessageTypes
    .Where(a => a.MessageTypeID == mt.MessageTypeID &&
          (a.ApplicationID == applicationId || !a.ApplicationID.HasValue)).DefaultIfEmpty()
where mtd.Culture == culture
select new ApplicationEditEventTypeModel
{
    ApplicationMessageTypeID = amt.ApplicationMessageTypeID ?? Guid.NewGuid(),
    Description = mtd.Description,
    MessageTypeID = mtd.MessageTypeID,
    EventForwardingRuleID = amt.EventForwardingRuleID ?? 0
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the ApplicationId clause doesn't really look like its part of the JOIN - i.e. it's not really part of the foreign key relationship - instead it's really just a normal WHERE condition.

So I'd recommend moving the ApplicationId out to WHERE in both the SQL and in the LINQ

```
DECLARE @p1 UniqueIdentifier SET @p1 = 'AC1D85C1-28F1-46A3-9C6A-3B7446609A2A'
DECLARE @p2 UniqueIdentifier SET @p2 = NEWID()
SELECT
    [MTD].[Description],
    [MTD].[MessageTypeID],
    ISNULL([AMT].[ApplicationMessageTypeID], NEWID()),
    ISNULL([AMT].[EventForwardingRuleID], '1001')
FROM [dbo].[MessageType] as [MT]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[MessageTypeDescription] AS [MTD] 
        ON [MT].[MessageTypeID] = [MTD].[MessageTypeID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ApplicationMessageType] AS [AMT] 
        ON [AMT].[MessageTypeID] = [MT].[MessageTypeID]
WHERE [MTD].[Culture] = 'fr'
        AND (AMT IS NULL OR ([AMT].[ApplicationID] = @p1 OR [AMT].[ApplicationID] IS NULL ))
```

and

```
(from mt in db.MessageTypes
join mtd in db.MessageTypeDescriptions
      on mt.MessageTypeID equals mtd.MessageTypeID
join amt in db.ApplicationMessageTypes
      on new mt.MessageTypeID equals amt.MessageTypeID
    into appMessageTypes
from amt in appMessageTypes.DefaultIfEmpty()
where mtd.Culture == culture
      && amt==null || (amt.ApplicationID == null || amt.ApplicationID == applicationId)
select new ApplicationEditEventTypeModel
{
 ApplicationMessageTypeID = amt.ApplicationMessageTypeID == null ? Guid.NewGuid() : amt.ApplicationMessageTypeID,
 Description = mtd.Description,
 MessageTypeID = mtd.MessageTypeID,
 EventForwardingRuleID = amt.EventForwardingRuleID == null ? 0 : amt.EventForwardingRuleID
});
```

You could probably also use a nested select (or a view) if you wanted to keep the ApplicationId clause closer to the original ApplicationMessageType table

Comment: It is not bad and actually was my first move to try to fix this. Unfortunately it needed to be inside the "join" clause.